# insert 3 list into mysql with python

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

I have 3 list like this:

```
list_model = [2000, 2010, 2020, 1998, 2016]
list_worked = [1200, 0, 45000, 123000]
list_price = [920000, 123000, 12, 6500]
```

and i want to INSERT them to MySQL database that describe like this:

```
+---------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| model   | int  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| worked  | int  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| price   | int  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I tried to use

```
cursor = mydb.cursor()
cursor.execute ("INSERT INTO l90 VALUES (%i, %i, %i)" % (list_model, list_karkard, list_gheymat ))
mydb.commit()
mydb.close()
```

but it says "TypeError: %i format: a number is required, not list"
and i don't know what i should to do can any one help me?

Comment: Do you want to insert 5*4*4=80 records (with all possible combinations), or you want to insert 5 records with positional matching (and 5th record will have NULL in `worked` and `price` because of difference in lists sizes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`cursor.executemany`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html), using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) to create a list of tuples to insert:

```
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO l90 VALUES (%i, %i, %i)",
                   [(m, w, p) for m, w, p in zip(list_model, list_worked, list_price)])
```

Note that it is good practice to enumerate the columns you are inserting into, this helps avoid issues when the structure of tables changes. You should write:

```
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO l90 (model, worked, price) VALUES (%i, %i, %i)",
                   [(m, w, p) for m, w, p in zip(list_model, list_worked, list_price)])
```